# Возможно ли продолжение работы скрипта после переадресации?

Tags: javascript

У меня следующая ситуация: есть некая страница в интернете, куда я могу внедрить свой javascript. Скрипт выполняет переадресацию на другой сайт, например, вот так:

```
document.location.replace("https://site.ru");
```

или так:

```
window.location.href = "https://site.ru";
```

Есть ли возможность продолжить выполнение этого же .js-файла, но когда откроется новая страница, после выполнения перехода по ссылке "site.ru" ? При условии, что внедрить свой скрипт на site.ru тем же способом я не могу. Про xss на site.ru мне тоже ничего не известно. Может быть есть другой способ?

Comment: Оно выполняет переадресацию куда? туда где его вы то же можете внедрить? Ваш вопрос не полный.

Comment: Мой скрипт выполняет переадресацию на совсем другой домен, изменить код сайта по ссылке тем же способом я не могу, только выполнить javascript до переадресации. А может быть есть возможность каким-то образом изменить исходный код страницы "site.ru", выполнив js-файл на предыдущей странице? Это тоже решит проблему.

Comment: Немного непонятно. Сначала Вы пишите, что "можете" внедрить скрипт. Потом - что не можете, и не знаете про xss на сайте. Если сайт защищен от xss-атак - Вы не сможете выполнить свой скрипт.

Comment: Я могу внедрить скрипт на другой сайт, не имеющий к "site.ru" никакого отношения.  В том и проблема, что я не могу внедрить скрипт на "site.ru" , хотя по сути и пытаюсь это сделать, но после переадресации выполнение моего скрипта прерывается.

Comment: В общем случае ответ будет нет, выполнение после переадресации невозможно. Можно открыть сайт `site.ru` в новом окне через `window.open` и продолжить выполнять скрипт в старом окне. Если же вы хотите выполнить свой скрипт на постороннем сайте, то это не получится т.к. это грубое нарушение безопасности.

Comment: Слава богу, что так нельзя делать.